# Generate ID from Product Name based on Matching Product Name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in which

```
ID  Product Name
1   Alto
2   Aveo
3   Aveo UVA
4   A star
5   Eeco
6   800
7   Omni
8   Zen
9   Zen Estilo
10  Versa
```

.... and so on of database of over 300 products

Now i have created a new sheet in the said spreadsheet
Have a created a drop down list to select from Product Name
However want ID to be automatically filled and in a separate column based on Product Name selected.

can any one help
Vlookup function or what else, not able to create
how to create matching id from the product name
[image]

[image]

Excel Sheet Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Index:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table-Code!$B$2:$B$300,MATCH(B2,Table-Code!$C$2:$C$300,0)),"")
```

Table-Code!$B$2:$B$300 is your initial Table-Code Id column change it to correspond your data

Table-Code!$B$2:$B$300 is your initial Table-Code Product column change it to correspond your data
B2 is where you have the drop down box Product Name, Model in Stock-List
In C2 write the formula
Iferror in case of no match or empty cell

Comment: thanks, i have modified question with attached pic of data. Can you help basis same

Comment: I modified the formula to correspond your Tables